# How to solve flutter image load, I want to use transparent_image library ? How to use it to load image from network?

Tags: flutter

I have an image like this below

```
Image.network('${video.image}',fit: BoxFit.cover)
```

Any Solution to load image faster. Thank in advance

Comment: You can create a loading screen, you can lower the resolution, or [in production] you can use CDN to bring it closer to the user device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transparent_image library from pub.dev, for code reference:

```
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                  placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                  image: '${video.image}',fit: BoxFit.fill,
                )
```